# What is item.bounds?

Tags: paperjs

What does `paper.view.bounds` actually return?

It seems to return a rectangle object along with multiple properties:

```
  Rectangle {height: 1200, width: 1920, y: 0, x: 0}
    height:    1200
    width    :    1920
    x    :    0
    y    :    0
    bottom    :    (...)
    bottomCenter    :    (...)
    bottomLeft    :    (...)
    bottomRight    :    (...)
    center    :    (...)
    centerX    :    (...)
    centerY    :    (...)
    empty    :    (...)
    left    :    (...)
    leftCenter    :    (...)
    point    :    (...)
    right    :    (...)
    rightCenter    :    (...)
    size    :    (...)
    top    :    (...)
    topCenter    :    (...)
    topLeft    :    (...)
    topRight    :    (...)
    __proto__    :    Base
```

Answer (score 1):

`bounds` refers to the *Bounding Box* of an `Item`.

Think of it as the minimum box needed to enclose your `Item`.

From [Wikipedia: Minimum Bounding Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box):

> In geometry, the minimum or smallest bounding or enclosing box for a point set (S) in N dimensions is the box with the smallest measure (area, volume, or hypervolume in higher dimensions) within which all the points lie. When other kinds of measure are used, the minimum box is usually called accordingly, e.g., "minimum-perimeter bounding box".

[image: Bounding-box illustration]